# How to clear auto complete results when input field is empty in Laravel + Vue Js?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Please am working on autoComplete Search bar and wants to clear the search if input field is empty. Currently, am able to display results but I still see the search result in my div when I clear the field. I want the div to go empty when i clear search input. Any assistance please

Vue code below

```
<template>
    <div style="margin-top:8px">
        <input type="text" v-model="form.user" v-on:keyup="show" class="form-control">
        <div class="panel-footer" v-if="results.length">
            <ul v-for="result in results" :key="result.id">
                <li>{{result.name}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {

    data(){
        return{
            form:{
                user: ""
            },
            results: []

        }
    },

    methods:{
        show(){
            axios.post('/users', this.form).then((res)=>{
                this.results = res.data
            })
        }

    }
    
}
</script>
```

***Controller***

```
public function getUser(Request $request){
        $qry = $request->input('user');
        $all_user = DB::table('users')
        ->where("name", "like", "%" . $qry . '%')
        ->get();
        return $all_user;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The div is rendered only when `results` array has items. So when `this.form.user` is empty you should also reset the `this.results`. You could use a [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) function for this.

Add this code between `data` and `methods`.

```
watch: {
  form: {
     handler(val){
        if(this.form.user == ""){
           this.results = [];
        }
     },
     deep: true
  }
}
```